# Where is node while using nvm?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am on a MacOS, and I switched from Homebrew Node to NVM, and removed Node from Homebrew but then a lot of my previous packages cannot find Node anymore (Sublime, Heroku etc)...so I have to manually update the location of Node to these packages.

Where is Node while using NVM?

Comment: When you issue **nvm use `node_version`** nvm will set the path to your node automatically.

Comment: `which node` should show you the location of the Node executable, but that location changes each time you change Node version with `nvm`. It's better to also have a globally installed Node (I'd suggest using the official Node installer for Mac).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can get the path to the executable to where node was installed with

```
nvm which node
```

Or any of the other NVM special aliases for node versions such as

```
nvm which default
```

Comment: what does it mean if nvm which node is different from which node?

Comment: or we can use `nvm which node` current to give the node binary path

Answer (score 10):

NVM should set PATH variable to your node installation directory, it does this automatically after:

```
nvm current use `nvm current`
```

You can check variables like this:

```
env | grep NVM
```

Here is my output:

```
NVM_DIR=/Users/name/.nvm
NVM_CD_FLAGS=-q
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://iojs.org/dist
NVM_PATH=/Users/name/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.0/lib/node
NVM_BIN=/Users/name/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.0/bin
```

Comment: Both answers are solid.  But this leads to more info that you may or may not be looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can locate your node by running `which node` or `command -v node`

Answer (score 5):

**nvm root** command gives us path of the node exe

Comment: This only works on the Windows implementation. Also, for me (as of 2022) it only shows where `nvm` itself is installed, not where the current node executable is.

Answer (score 4):

Trying all the answers in 2023, nothing works:

> nvm which node

nvm: Unknown command or option: "which" (see nvm -h for usage)

> env|grep NVM

> nvm root

nvm: Unknown command or option: "root" (see nvm -h for usage)

And finally!

> env|grep nvm

nvm_current_version=v19.6.0
PATH=**~/.local/share/nvm/v19.6.0/bin**:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

So I guess currently NVM keeps node in `~/.local/share/nvm`

Comment: `nvm which node` works fine on MacOS in 2023.